# batch file to find text and generate a report

Tags: batch-file, cmd, find, findstr

I have previously managed to achieve what I need to in CMD, but I'm now trying to write a batch file, and have failed miserably.

Every month I import data into a program which provides a log file. I want to search this log file for `rejected` and export that data into a text file.

Then, I want to search that text file, and exclude 2 or 3 items of text, to finally end up with `2` text files.

1. with all of the rejections
2. with all of the rejections except for x and y (maybe z)

As I want to to role this out to other users, I have also asked it to create a new folder if one doesn't exist.

```
if not exist "C:\Airbus\Import_Errors\" md "C:\Airbus\Import_Errors\
find "rejected" "C:\Airbus\Local_LPCPERFO\9.4.3\admin\log\PAAdminImportAirport.log" > "C:\Airbus\Import_Errors\AllRejections.txt"
 findstr /i /v "1500.0 45.0 1000.0" C:\Airbus\Import_Errors\AllRejections.txt" >> C:\Airbus\Import_Errors\uncommon_rejected.txt
```

Please help, I have tried and tried, and I can't get it to work. The last file doesn't actually generate a `.txt` file, but if I remove everything after the `>>` it displays the results in the CMD window.

Comment: You're missing a `"` in front of `C:\Airbus\Import_Errors\AllRejections.txt"` on the last line.

Comment: You're missing a `"` after `"C:\Airbus\Import_Errors\ ` on the first line. I should also mention that your `findstr` match uses a period `.` as a wildcard for any character.

Comment: Thank you. I have amended the " and removed the period from the findrstr. so I now have:
'if not exist "C:\Airbus\Import_Errors\" md "C:\Airbus\Import_Errors\" && find "rejected" "C:\Airbus\Local_LPCPERFO\9.4.3\admin\log\PAAdminImportAirport.log" > "C:\Airbus\Import_Errors\AllRejections.txt" && findstr /i /v "1500 45 1000" C:\Airbus\Import_Errors\AllRejections.txt" >> "C:\Airbus\Import_Errors\uncommon_rejected.txt"'

i'm still not getting the last .txt file I get the error 
FINDSTR: Cannot open C:\Airbus\Import_Errors\AllRejections.txt >> C:\Airbus\Import_Errors\uncommon_rejected.txt

Comment: You are still missing a `"`. Check your code carefully.